# FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.readGenerateAuthTokenResponse java.lang.AbstractMethodError - abstract method "N.f N.f.d1(int)"

Tags: flutter, firebase

I recently installed `Firebase` on my Flutter App to use `Firebase Crashlytics` and `Analytics`. After published the updates on Play Store I noticed a lot of crashes on Android Devices.[image: Issue Description]

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "N.f N.f.d1(int)"
       at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.readGenerateAuthTokenResponse(FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:90)
       at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.b(FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:96)
       at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.fetchAuthTokenFromServer(FirebaseInstallations.java:29)
       at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCallIfNecessary(FirebaseInstallations.java:110)
       at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doRegistrationOrRefresh$3(FirebaseInstallations.java:110)
       at com.google.firebase.concurrent.SequentialExecutor$1.run(SequentialExecutor.java:2)
       at com.google.firebase.concurrent.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.workOnQueue(SequentialExecutor.java:84)
       at com.google.firebase.concurrent.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.run(SequentialExecutor.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(CustomThreadFactory.java:13)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Now I want to publish an update to solve this issue
Below is what I use so far

`android/build.gradle`

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'
    }
```

`android/app/build.gradle`
`google-services.json` is also included in the project

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

`pubspec.yaml` related packages

```
  firebase_core: ^2.15.1
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's a known issue. Try to update pro-guard

```
-keep class com.google.firebase.installations.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.**
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.firebase.* { *; }
-keep interface com.google.firebase.installations.** {*;}
```

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9884